# ASP.NET Textbox's autocomplete is not working on IE9

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9

Title says pretty much everything. I got a form where the user has to input some data let's say and ID (1234). If he comes back, I want that entry to be visible through the browsers autocomplete feature.

Right now, it isn't working on IE9. I tried it on Chrome and it works flawlessly. The problem is that the client wants it on IE.

Here's what I've tried so far:
- I've enabled autocompletion in my IE options : Internet Options > Content > autocompletion  and I checked all the options.

- Checked some registry key under Software > internet explorer > control panel (which doesn't exist in Win 7)
- Set the attribute to something not "off".

I'm pretty clueless. IS the problem IE9 or my page? Seeing it working on Chrome makes me think that it is the browser, but we never know.

Thanks

-- Edit

Ok sorry, Maybe I haven't been clear enough (probably not). I got an asp page with a text box. that textbox is supposed to autocomplete the entry the user is entering by default.

It is working in Chrome, but not in IE for some reason. I googled the whole day to find a solution . There is no javascript, no ajax control nothing. Just the basic thing doesn't work. I tested it in a different page of the same project and it worked. but that specific page doesn't.  That asp page has a masterPageFile and is using the  component.

So my question is : What can make a textbox autocomplete not work?

Comment: You will have to demonstrate what you mean, with a jsFiddle, because I don't understand your problem at all. What do the "internet options > ... > autocompletion" have to do with your jQuery autocomplete? Your post is really confusing and making links with different things that don't have anything to do with each other.

Comment: Are you having problems using an autocomplete JavaScript enabled input box? Or are you asking about leveraging the browser's built in autocomplete functionality?

Comment: Ok sorry, Maybe I haven't been clear enough (probably not).
I got an asp page with a text box. that textbox is supposed to autocomplete the entry the user is entering by default. It is working in Chrome, but not in IE for some reason. I googled the whole day to find a solution . There is no javascript, no ajax control nothing. Just the basic thing doesn't work. I tested it in a different page of the same project and it worked. but that specific page don`t.

Comment: That asp page has a masterPageFile and is using the <asp:content> component.

Comment: Styxxy , sorry, I'm just trying to enumerate the solutions I found on the internet so far.

Comment: based on what i currently believe the problem to be (IE is not using autocomplete feature for one of your web pages), you may have better luck on superuser.com.  Only thing I can think off that might affect it off the top of my head is check to see if the textbox has a name and ID.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Not sure why it was doing that but removing that line in one of my embedded master page fixed it.

Could someone explain it to me ?

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" Namespace="ProjectName.Reports" Assembly="ProjectName" %>.